# Modificar validador de QLineEdit en función del QRadioButton marcado

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-3.7, pyqt

Tengo un inconveniente al cambiar el tipo de datos que se introduzca en el **QLineEdit**, cuando doy clic en el boton de radio **Código** el formulario solamente me permite introducir numeros y eso esta bien, pero cuando doy clic en el boton de radio **Nombre** y antes habia clicado el boton anterior solo me permite introducir numeros, cuando deberia de dejarme introducir cadenas de texto quiere decir que se queda con la configuracion anterior y deberia de cambar el QLineEdit a tipo cadena.

Si alguien conoce la manera de hacerlo por favor colaborar, gracias

Les muestro el codigo que llevo hasta ahora

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Eliminar(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(450, 310)

        # ---------------------------------------- Contenedor ----------------------------------------
        caja = QGroupBox(self)
        caja.setGeometry(20, 20, 410, 210)

        # ---------------------------------------- Label ----------------------------------------
        texto = QLabel("Eliminar por:", caja)
        texto.setFont(QFont("Consolas", 14))
        texto.move(20, 20)

        # ---------------------------------------- Formulario ----------------------------------------
        self.formulario = QLineEdit(caja)
        self.formulario.setGeometry(105, 140, 200, 30)
        self.formulario.setFont(QFont("Comic Sans MS", 14))
        self.formulario.setReadOnly(True)

        # ---------------------------------------- Botones de radio ----------------------------------------
        self.codigo_radio = QRadioButton("Código", caja)
        self.codigo_radio.setGeometry(50, 60, 80, 20)
        self.codigo_radio.setFont(QFont("Consolas", 14))
        self.codigo_radio.toggled.connect(self.check)

        self.nombre_radio = QRadioButton("Nombre", caja)
        self.nombre_radio.setGeometry(50, 90, 80, 20)
        self.nombre_radio.setFont(QFont("Consolas", 14))
        self.nombre_radio.toggled.connect(self.check)


    # ---------------------------------------- Funciones ----------------------------------------
    def check(self):

        if self.codigo_radio.isChecked() == True:

            self.formulario.setPlaceholderText("Ingrese el código")
            self.formulario.setValidator(QIntValidator())
            self.formulario.clear()
            self.formulario.setReadOnly(False)

        if self.nombre_radio.isChecked() == True:

            self.formulario.setPlaceholderText("Ingrese el nombre")
            self.formulario.clear()
            self.formulario.setReadOnly(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication([])
    window = Eliminar()
    window.show()
    qApp.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una vez que asignas el validador en ningún momento lo eliminas, en el condicional
`if self.nombre_radio.isChecked()` debes eliminar el validador para el `QLineEdit` o, de haber sido seleccionado el botón para el código, se seguirá usando el `QIntValidator` asignado.

Para eliminar el validador basta con **volver a llamar a `QLineEdit.setValidator` y pasar `None` como argumento.**

Por otro lado, `toggled` causa que se llame a `check` dos veces ya que la señal se genera tanto cuando un botón es seleccionado como cuando se desmarca. Seria más adecuado usar la señal `clicked`.

```
self.codigo_radio.clicked.connect(self.check)
self.nombre_radio.clicked.connect(self.check)
```

El slot debería quedar así:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def check(self):
    if self.codigo_radio.isChecked():
        self.formulario.setPlaceholderText("Ingrese el código")
        self.formulario.setValidator(QIntValidator())

    elif self.nombre_radio.isChecked():
        self.formulario.setPlaceholderText("Ingrese el nombre")
        self.formulario.setValidator(None)

    self.formulario.clear()
    self.formulario.setReadOnly(False)
```

Comment: Buena esa parcero